# Are IAP possible while maintaining "Data Not Collected" Privacy Policy?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

I'm working on implementing In app purchases for an app. I looked at revenue cats and other 3rd party SDKs, but they require a change in the privacy policy of the app, as shown here: https://ibb.co/mhdsdB1

I can uncheck a few boxes and get the following privacy policy, which is better but still not what I want: https://ibb.co/3S5H1nV

I'm wondering if it is even possible to implement In app purchases and maintain the "Data Not Collected" Policy, or if "Data Not Linked to You" Is the best I can get while still doing IAP, weather that be through storekit or a 3rd party program?

Comment: Old question but maybe you managed to get an answer to your question. Maybe you could add it as an answer in that case? Cheers!